# Selenium2 WebDriver Ruby => how click on a hidden link

Tags: ruby, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium 2 WebDriver on Ruby.

How it is possible click on hidden link, with css (display: none)? 
the link is submenu and is visible when mouse over on menu.

//EDIT:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"submenu2"}
```

I changed ':id' to ':link_text', because the submenu have no id's.
the Navigation:

```
<ul id="nav-main">
 -<li class="menu active">
    <p>
      <a href="/menu1">menu1</a>
    </p>
   -<ul> <-- begin display:none
     -<li>
        <p>
          <a href="/submenu1">submenu1</a>
        </p>
      </li>
     +<li>
    </ul> <--end submenu
  </li>
</ul>
```

you can see the submenu, when mouseover menu. Before are the submenu for webdriver not exist.

with followed code I see the link from menu1 in FF left-bottom, but the submenu is not opened and break with a timeout error.

```
menu = @driver.find_element(:link_text => "menu")
@driver.action.move_to(menu).perform
wait.until {
  @driver.find_element(:link_text => "submenu").click
}
```

Answer (score 5):

WebDriver emulates user actions, and doesn't allow clicking elements that a user wouldn't be able to click.

So you should do what a user would do: mouse over the menu before clicking. In Ruby you could do e.g.:

```
menu = driver.find_element(:id => "menu")
submenu = driver.find_element(:id => "submenu")

driver.action.move_to(menu).click(submenu).perform
```

The ActionBuilder class (returned by Driver#action) is documented [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html).

Comment: Sounds very reasonable but it's not working in my case. Submenu is displayed by li:hover { display: block } and I get still get ElementNotDisplayedError in WebDriver.

Answer (score 1):

before you search the link and click it

```
@driver.execute_script('jQuery(":hidden","#nav-main").show()')
```

jQuery should be loaded

Answer (score 0):

In the past, if I have not had much luck with the ActionBuilder methods, I just use pure javascript:

```
def mouse_over_and_out(element)
  @driver.execute_script("if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}", element)
  yield element
  @driver.execute_script("if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseout', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseout');}", element)
end

def wait_for_visibility(element) 
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)
  wait.until do
    element.visible?
  end
  element
end

mouse_over_and_out(@driver.find_element(:css => "ul#nav-main li")) do |menu|
  submenu = menu.find_element(:css => "ul li a")
  wait_for_visibility(submenu).click
end
```