# Ruby Mouse Over is not long enough, may need a delay of some sort

Tags: ruby, mouse, delay, mouseover

Hope you all are well. This is my first post.

I am trying to write a script in Ruby using Cucumber and the Selenium 2 framework.

I am trying to find out how to click on any given link on a hover based component.

The sainsbury's website http://www.sainsburys-live-well-for-less.co.uk/ is the perfect example.

If you select the first link i.e. Recipes and Insprirations followed by Lets get backing then you are redirected to a new page.

I want to do this through a script.

Currently I am having issues displaying the overlay components which appears when placing the mouse cursor over the Recipes & Inspiration button.

I am able to make the hover over component appear using the @driver.mouse.move_to ele function. The next step would be to look through the collection, find the element and click on it but the problem is that there are too many steps involved and by the time I even get to check the number of items in the hidden panel, the panel dissapears.

I have also tried using the Ruby Builder but had no luck. If someone can help me out and use the sainsbury website as an example then it would help out greatly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the sleep command followed by the number of seconds that you want selenium to wait before executing the next step. For example..:

```
sleep 2
```

Will wait for 2 seconds before moving onto the next line of your script.

Also check 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777886/selenium2-webdriver-ruby-how-click-on-a-hidden-link)
answer for clicking hidden menus..

Okay. Because I remember how it is when you start. There you go. I've done this for you..

```
require "selenium-webdriver"          
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox     
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

driver.navigate.to('http://www.sainsburys-live-well-for-less.co.uk/')   

menu = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@id='recipes-inspiration-menu']")
submenu = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//li[@class='first first-child  children']")

driver.action.move_to(menu).click(submenu).perform

driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[@title='Let's Get Baking']").click
```

As I said, download and install Firebug it would help you a lot..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sleep does not work because sleep, as you said, goes to the next line of code when the sleep has finished. I need a way for the move_to line of code to remain active whilst other lines of code are running i.e. i need the hidden menu to remain visible whilst my script is looking for all the links and then clicking on them. I also checked the link you provided but it does not help because the second click to link is invisible to the script until the hidden menu is visible.

Comment: question: how you go about locating your web-element? Do you know there is a very useful Firefox add-on called firebug..check it out!

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the help. I am using firebug. I could have used xpath myself but am not because the webpage may change on day and as a result will break the entire script. My logic is the following:Hover over button and check to see hidden panel is displayed. Check all elements in the hidden item and look for the specific one. When the specific item has been found, click on it. The issue is the hidden panel does not stay long enough. I essentially need to find a solution to do this without using xpath. If i use xpath then my script will become redundent if the web page changes.

Comment: I get what you mean about the script becoming 'fragile' to change but that is something you need to deal with by grabbing the most 'solid' elements that are unlikely to change. I believe what you are trying to achieve is oxymoron as this sentence of yours DOESN'T make sense--> '..Check all elements in the hidden item and look for the specific one..' the term SPECIFIC one you cannot denote it relatively in my humble opinion..maybe I'm wrong but good luck anyway to what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help. After using perform it looks like perform caused a delay which was perfect.

Comment: glad i could help man..let me know with a comment here if you managed to do it your way eventually..take care and have a nice weekend man! :)